# Does functional programming use "class methods"? OO -> Functional thinking

Tags: swift, functional-programming

Here is a simple Node class

```
class Node: {
   let uuid: String
   var children = [Node]()

   init() {
      self.uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
   }

   func addChild(node: Node) {
      children.append(node)
   }

   func removeChild(node: Node) {
      if let index = self.children.indexOf(node) {
         children.removeAtIndex(index)
      }
   }
}
```

To use pure functions I rewrote Node in a way that addChild and removeChild return new Node instead of mutating inner children array, by implementing "global" functions appendChildToNode, removeChildFromNode:

```
struct Node: {
   let uuid: String
   let children = [Node]()

   init(uuid: NSString, children: [Node]) {
      self.uuid = uuid
      self.children = children;
   }
}

func appendChildToNode(node: Node, #child: Node) -> Node {
   return Node(uuid: node.uuid, children: node.children + [child])
}

func removeChildFromNode(node: Node, #child: Node) -> Node {
   return Node(uuid: node.uuid, children: node.children.filter { $0 != child })
}
```

I didn't add appendChildToNode, removeChildFromNode as class methods because

Node.appendChild(child) on glance to me implies that original node will be changed and nothing will be returned (although it can be implemented to return new Node). I'm getting that impression because i.e. in Swift array.appendObject(object) will  mutate original array, and after years of OO way of thinking.

What would be the best practice/preference in functional programming ?

appendChildToNode(node, child) or class methods ? (Node.appendChild(child)) ?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, I prefer to avoid making things instance methods when I don't need them to be. Although "dot notation" is nice, methods use dynamic dispatching (allowing their implementation to change in a subclass) and this makes things a bit more complex to reason about than just using a regular function.

That said, the real best practice I would recommend here is to use names for your functions that don't sound like they are mutating things. For example, `appendChildToNode` sounds like its mutating the list even if its coded as a static function. Instead of that I would prefer something like `cons` (the traditional name for this operation on immutable linked lists) or `listNode` (a noun representing the result of the operation instead of a verb indication the action)